# Set Background Color of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I wanted to set the background color of my Navigation drawer in java but it seems as `setBackgroundColor` and all similar methods have no effect.
Only the XML line `android:background="@color/mycolor"` is working. If remove the xml line and try one of the methods the drawer just stays transparent.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor)?

Comment: What do you mean ? The view that comes from the left ? It takes the color of the view you put inside, so what is the problem ?

Comment: Sorry guys for not putting the code up there. I just solved my issue. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just solved my own problem.

I totally forgot that it's not the `DrawerLayout` I want to set the background to, but the `ListView` inside.

I admit I made it somewhat hard for you guys without adding code to my post -.-'

So instead of:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
(...)
mDrawerLayout.setBackgroundResource(int);
```

I had to do this:

```
private ListView mDrawerList;
(...)
mDrawerList.setBackgroundResource(int);
```

Answer (score 92):

In your activity_main.xml include the following

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer"
    android:background="@color/color_navigation_list_background"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/color_selector_navigation_item"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

cast your navigation drawer to navigationView and do as follows

```
 navigationView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

Comment: how to you set the background color of each menu item to different colors?