# Changing background Color of DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-drawer

I'm trying to change the color of the DrawerLayout in my app

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF">
```

As seen above, I've tried android:background and android:backgroundTint but they both don't seem to be working. Help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17092687/set-background-color-of-navigation-drawer

Comment: add the color to your listview ...or `navigationView` inside the `DrawerLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Set background color to the second embedded view, e.g. to the ListView in this example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/activity_navigation_app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list_drawer_menu"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
          android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
          android:background="#FFFFFF"
          android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing `DrawerLayout` background, you should change its child `NavigationView` or `ListView` background color.

**#** If you are using `NavigationView` inside your `DrawerLayout`, then just change the `background` of `NavigationView`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    ................
    ....................
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

**#** If you are using `ListView` inside your `DrawerLayout`, then just change the `background` of `ListView`.

```
<ListView
    ................
    ....................
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

I want to set the background of listview under drawerlayout so i had to do this..

```
mDrawerList.setBackgroundResource(int);
```